# Monthly Counts determined by time range

Tags: sql-server, monthcalendar

I have a query which brings back the count of rows (distinct child_name) for the period of one month. I would like to write a query so I can bring back a total for multiple  months. I would like the to be be able to select a time range and have the months in the range I select automatic calculate without hard coding for each month. I read some info on loops and sequences but I found it hard to understand.

```
DECLARE @From_DT DATE = '2012-07-01', @To_DT DATE = '2013-7-30';

SELECT count(Child_Name) as July12_Count
FROM ECMS_BACKUP.dbo.vw_B2H_CLIENTS
WHERE CLT_NBR IN (SELECT CLT_NBR FROM ECMS_BACKUP.dbo.ufn_B2H_Enrolled_Clients_List(@From_DT,  @To_DT))
```

I would like a result like the below without hard coding.

If I were to select:

```
 DECLARE @From_DT DATE = '2012-07-01', @To_DT DATE = '2013-10-31';
```

I would get this:

```
July12_Count  Aug13_Count  Sep13_Count  Oct13_Count  

251           255          250          245
```

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if `ufn_B2H_Enrolled_Clients_List(@From_DT, @From_DT)` should be `ufn_B2H_Enrolled_Clients_List(@From_DT, @To_DT)` (note the change from `@From_DT` to `@To_DT`)

Comment: @Martin Parkin Yes, it should be From_DT to To_DT. Thanks.

Comment: What is the maximum time-frame between `@From_DT` AND `@To_DT` ? Less than 1 year or greater ? What if some users execute this stored procedure using these parameters: `'2012-01-01'` & `'2013-0-30'` ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Yes, One year

Comment: Then you should check these parameters. What should happens if a user enters following values: `'2012-01-15'` & `'2013-01-14'` ? Your query will return rows from `January 2012` and from `January 2013`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to assume that one of the columns in `vw_B2H_CLIENTS` is the date you are filtering by.

In this case, you could try using `DATEPART` in order to group by the month (replacing `DATE_COL` by your date column), as so:

```
SELECT DATEPART(month, DATE_COL) AS Month,
       COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM ECMS_BACKUP.dbo.vw_B2H_CLIENTS
  WHERE CLT_NBR IN (SELECT CLT_NBR FROM ECMS_BACKUP.dbo.ufn_B2H_Enrolled_Clients_List(@From_DT, @To_DT))
  GROUP BY DATEPART(month, DATE_COL)
```

Also note that you may have an error in `ufn_B2H_Enrolled_Clients_List` as you have `@From_DT` as the parameter twice (you may want `@To_DT`).

This would give you output like this:

```
Month   Count
7       251
8       255
9       250
10      245
```

Comment: Great thanks. When I run this I get the errors:  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid column name 'DATE_COL'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'DATE_COL'.

Comment: As I said, make sure you: `replace DATE_COL by your date column`. So you must use the date column you filter by in the `vw_B2H_CLIENTS` table\view for this to work.  There are two instances of `DATE_COL` to replace (one in the `SELECT` and one in the `GROUP BY`) - make sure you get both.